# Are these two snippets of code equivalent (implementing siamese RNN network using Keras)?

Tags: keras

I want to implement a siamese RNN network where the two legs of this net are shared and at every time step, the RNN take CNN output as input,  like this:

```
   X1    X2    X3    X4             Y1    Y2    Y3    Y4
    |     |     |     |              |     |     |     |
   CNN   CNN   CNN   CNN            CNN   CNN   CNN   CNN
    |     |     |     |              |     |     |     |
   RNN-->RNN-->RNN-->RNN--->[][]<---RNN<--RNN<--RNN<--RNN
                             ||
                         Classifier
```

I'm implementing it using Keras TimeDistributed Wrapper in this way:

```
cnn = InceptionV3(include_top=False)(input_im)
cnn = Flatten()(cnn)
# Use one TimeDistributed
cnn = TimeDistributed(Model(input=input_im, output=cnn))
rnn = LSTM(64)(cnn)

leg_a = Input(shape=sequence_shape)
leg_b = Input(shape=sequence_shape)
leg_a = rnn(leg_a)
leg_b = rnn(leg_b)
merged = merge([leg_a, leg_b], mode='concat', concat_axis=-1)
merged = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(merged)
```

I dont know if the above code is equivalent with the following:

```
# Use one TimeDistributed for one layer respectively
cnn = TimeDistributed(InceptionV3(include_top=False))(input_im)
cnn = TimeDistributed(Flatten())(cnn)
cnn = Model(input=input_im, output=cnn)
rnn = Sequential()
rnn.add(cnn)
rnn.add(LSTM(64))
...
...
```

In both settings, the model can work well with the same input. But is there any difference between these two implementations? Or there is another way to write?